# preview word document from local server using google doc

Tags: fancybox, google-docs

I am trying to display my word document using fancybox with the link as:

`<a href="https://docs.google.com/gview?url=http:/localhost:8080/DocumentManager/uploads/CVs.doc&embedded=true"></a>`

But the url is not working. Please suggest me the solutions for this problem.

Comment: try adding `type: "iframe"` to the fancybox API options in your custom script

Comment: @JFK The problem's the same here. If I add iframe the same problem is displayed on a fancy box's iframe. The problem is displayed as **Sorry, we were unable to find the document at the original source. Verify that the document still exists.
You can also try to download the original document by clicking here. ** on a google doc's url.

Comment: Check http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/9617 and http://www.gdocsopen.com/

Answer (score -1):

Please try this to view documents

`<a herf="https://docs.google.com/gview?url=http%3A%2F%2flocalhost%3A8080%2FDocumentManager%2Fuploads%2FCVs.doc&embedded=true"></a>`

I hope it is working f9